# In java How to find a word in a string and copy it to another string variable?

Tags: java, xml, string

Hi I have the following string variable -

```
 [  <row id="0">
    <test>123abc</test>
    <INV>123456789</INV>
    </row>
   ,
    <row id="1">
    <test>456def</test>
    <INV>123456789</INV>
    </row>
 ]
```

Its an `xml` but I am sending this inside `java` code as a pure string -

```
String check = inXml;
System.out.println("incoming payload is "+check);
check = check.replaceAll(",","");
check = check.replaceAll("\\[", "");
check = check.replaceAll("\\]", "");
```

I used `replaceAll` to replace "[",","and "]" now i want the values in test to be stored in a separate string like String s=123abc,456def

Comment: Do you need to obtain the values in the xml String..? or just want to do some fun tasks..? If you're developing an application, you should use jaxb xml to object conversion instead of manually doing it...

Comment: No i dont want it as xml i just need it as a string but i wanna find the characters after <test>

Comment: your goal is to convert an xml data (even if it's a string xml) into its appropriate variables?

Comment: my goal is to extract the values in the test element don't consider it as xml consider it as string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a parser. However, if you don't want, you can write a regex that extract the values for you, for example:

```
String line = <yout_html_string>

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<test>(.*?)</test>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);

while (m.find()) {
    // m.group(1) is the text you want
    // store it in a variable
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks but how do i make it a single string like 123abc,456def i used cancat function but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Option1: use dom parser. Very easy to use. From that get the node 'test' and get the value inside that tag.

Option2: use substr() to find the an exact match of . Now you know the start position of your substring and also the amount of characters it will be (6), and hence find the string from position of your substring + 7

Comment: If i go with option 2 test comes two times how can i do that

Comment: run it in a loop. first time you have found the start position, find the value. now your inpur string should change to all that remains from position where your </test> ends till end of the string.
But this is not at all a good way of programming. Better would be to use XML parsers and get the job done